# build nedit-ng : error dyld[45834]: Symbol not found: __ZNKSt3_V214error_category10_M_messageB5cxx11Ei / Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib

Tags: c++, macos, qt, gcc, g++

I try to build nedit-ng from [the github](https://github.com/eteran/nedit-ng) under `macOS Monterey 12.2`.

I can build the executable `nedit-ng` with `gcc-9` and `g++-9` from `brew` install.

But at the execution, I get the following error :

```
$ ./nedit-ng

dyld[52683]: Symbol not found: __ZNKSt3_V214error_category10_M_messageB5cxx11Ei
  Referenced from: /Users/fab/Install_Programmes/nedit-ng/build/nedit-ng
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
zsh: abort      ./nedit-ng
```

and I can't manage to fix this.

If I do a `otool -L` on executable, I get :

```
$ otool -L nedit-ng
nedit-ng:
    /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork (compatibility version 5.15.0, current version 5.15.2)
    /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml (compatibility version 5.15.0, current version 5.15.2)
    /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (compatibility version 5.15.0, current version 5.15.2)
    /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.15.0, current version 5.15.2)
    /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.15.0, current version 5.15.2)
    /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.15.0, current version 5.15.2)
    /usr/local/opt/gcc@6/lib/gcc/6/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.22.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/gcc/6/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

this may come from the line `/usr/local/opt/gcc@6/lib/gcc/6/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.22.0)` : indeed, it is indicated `gcc@6` whereas for compiling, I have used `gcc@9` : it is just a suggestion, maybe nothing related to my issue.

Could anyone see what's wrong at first sight ?

Comment: At first sight... does the libstdc++ exist within the gcc@9 tree structure?  If so, does changing the install_name to it fix the prob?

Comment: @RichardBarber . Thanks for your answer. actually, adding `libstdc++` of `gcc@9` to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` solved my issue. Regards